# Making a list view skip its parent's padding while maintaining clickability

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview, flutter-column

Here's my ListView. I want it to be clickable not just visible, while skipping its parent column's padding. Right now it's just visible and not clickable because of the OverflowBox widget.

```dart
   return SizedBox(
      height: 65,
      child: OverflowBox(
        maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: galleryItems.length,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          itemBuilder: (_, idx) {
            final galleryItem = galleryItems[idx];
            return InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                Get.to(
                  () => CustomerPictureScreen(),
                  arguments: {
                    'galleryImage': galleryItem.galleryImage,
                  },
                );
              },
              child: GalleryItemDetailsScreen(
                galleryImage: galleryItem.galleryImage,
                galleryImageId: galleryItem.galleryImageId,
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here's my column:

```dart
return Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
      top: small + 4,
      left: medium,
      right: medium,
    ),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        LabelSection(text: 'About', style: headingBookingScreen),
        SizedBox(
          height: medium,
        ),
        AboutSection(
          about: about,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: medium,
        ),
        LabelSection(
          text: 'Gallery',
          style: headingBookingScreen,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: medium,
        ),
        const GalleryDetailsScreen(),
        SizedBox(
          height: medium,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
}
```

Here's what I mean in pictures:

[image: ListView of Images1]

[image: ListView of images2]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To make a ListView clickable and skip its parent column's padding, you can wrap the ListView widget with a GestureDetector and adjust the padding accordingly. Here's an example code snippet to demonstrate this:

```
Column(
 children: [
 Padding(
   padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
   child: GestureDetector(
     onTap: () {
       // Handle ListView click event here
     },
     child: OverflowBox(
        maxHeight: 200.0, // Set the desired height
        child: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: [
           // Your ListView items here
         ],
       ),
     ),
   ),
 ),
],)
```

In the above code, the ListView is wrapped with a **GestureDetector** widget to make it clickable. The GestureDetector's **onTap callback** is where you can handle the click event. The Padding widget is used to add the desired padding around the ListView. The **OverflowBox widget** ensures that the ListView can exceed the parent's constraints and display its full content.

Comment: It's still not working.